# How to set which GRUB loader to use after dual booting two Linux OSes?

Tags: grub2

After installing Kali and accidentally its Grub-loader, I want to change it to the previous one of my Ubuntu installation. The reason is that the Ubuntu grub-loader can Secure boot while Kali's does not, whereby i have to keep this parameter disabled.

Answer (score 1):

This used to confuse me, too. I finally realized that I should choose one and only one system for grub to be configured on. Once I did that, it was a piece of cake. Install a new Linux, try to get it to not install grub (and, if it does anyway, delete it), then go to the controlling Linux system and run update-grub or grub-mkconfig (depending on the distro).

Comment: That might work. Surprisingly, with Secure boot enabled the kali grub didn't boot. I got an error message and thereafter i was redirected to the Ubuntu grub. Bang! So it is there waiting it's turn to be loaded.

Comment: It worked for me! Just erased the grubx64.efi from the boot folder, and now I can secure boot through Ubuntu's grub.